# Force audio through internal speaker (and headphones)

Tags: 22.04, headphones, speakers

Im installing ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop, the problem is that I damaged the headphone socket and it thinks there is always headphones plugged in. I know how to solve it in windows so I can force audio to play from both the speakers and the headphones at the same time.

Is this possible in ubuntu/linux ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into pavucontrol

install it `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` then go to "Output Devices" normaly you should see your laptop and the headphone then click on "configuration" and select "Analog stereo Duplex" as the profile, this allow you to play from both simultaneously, then go to "playback" and select the application that you want to play audio from, under "output" select "Simultaneous Output to Built-in Audio" to direct the audio to both.